# ASyncTask does not execute when task.execute() is called

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an Android application which has the main UI thread, and several other worker threads which I have spawned using ASyncTask.

However, there is a scenario that I can produce every time in which I attempt to spawn a new thread with ASyncTask using task.execute(), and it does not call doInBackground().  The thread never seems to start.  Then my application seems to spin for a little while, and then begins to hang.

Here are the threads I am using:
[image]

And here is the memory usage on the device:

[image]

It does not look as though it is failing to spawn due to memory issues.

Is there some other underlying reason that I do not know of?  Maximum number of threads?  Is there any way for me to find out why it is not executing?

Comment: show as your code so that we could help you solve your problem...

Comment: I have thousands of lines of code... the main relevant lines of code are the task instantiation and task.execute()... everything else around there is probably too much to show and explain.  I am looking for higher level guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AsyncTask uses a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) used internally with a core pool size of 5 and a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). In simpler terms: you can have atmost 5 AsyncTasks active at the same time. Additional tasks will be queued till one of the other AsyncTasks does not return from doInBackground().

You may want to review your code to free up some AsyncTasks. If thats not possible, you can try to create a CustomAsyncTask class in your project based on the original AsyncTask code which can be found [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java;h=5fb1d7c32879352170abbd6c56c1aa81f5fae175;hb=refs/heads/gingerbread). Try setting the CORE_POOL_SIZE variable to a higher value or using a [SynchronousQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html).

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the docs?

> Note: this function schedules the task on a queue for a single
>   background thread or pool of threads depending on the platform
>   version. When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a
>   single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a
>   **pool of threads** allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. After
>   HONEYCOMB, it is planned to change this **back to a single thread** to
>   avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. If you
>   truly want parallel execution, you can use the
>   executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR; however, see commentary there for warnings on
>   its use.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out.  somehow, I blindly missed this.  I am using Android 2.2.2, so I should have a pool of threads.  Therefore, shouldn't my ASyncTask operate in parallel instead of blocking to execute?  (meaning, I would not need to use executeOnExecutor)